# Can't execute net use from batch file - network path was not found

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have a batch file that includes these lines:

```
set /p _usern=Username: 
net use g: \\servername\d$ /user:%usern%
```

If I run these commands directly from a command prompt window, the path is found and the appropriate error (username/password incorrect) is displayed, if necessary. The drive is otherwise mapped as expected.

If I run these same exact commands from a batch file, either normal or admin, I receive this error:

```
System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found.
```

Why do these commands work from a command prompt window and not a batch file?

Comment: You have `_usern` in the first line and `usern` (no `_`) in the second line.

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot, I knew it would be something simple. Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem - we all make silly mistakes ;)